# Why my list became an int and how to resolve it

Tags: python-2.7

I got an issue with the following code :

```
def foo():
    return 1,"str",3,4

def bar():
    return 5

    lst_c1 = []
    lst_c2 = []
    lst_c1 = foo()
    lst_c2 = bar()
    print(type(lst_c2))
    lst_p = lst_c1 + lst_c2
    print(lst_p)
```

I wanted to merge both list in one but i got the following error :

```
    lst_p = lst_c1 + lst_c2
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

First, why when i declare lst_c1 = [] it has the tuple type, shouldn't it be a list ?
And then, why a list (or visibly a tuple) with a single item isn't considered as a tuple or a list.
I suppose that when you use '=' it changes the type, but is this possible to keep the type of lst_c2 with a method ?

```
lst_c2 =bar()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to concatenate those two, just change the `bar()` into:

```
def bar():
    return 5,
```

This way it will return a `tuple`, same as `foo()`.

Comment: I understand, but if i want a list ? And if i can't modify the return of my function ?

Comment: @MendyAbessira Then you need to wrap it outside with `(bar(), )`. Take note that you can concatenate `list` with `list` and `tuple` with `tuple` but not one with another.